# How can I change CSS generated by Bootstrap in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm new in Angular and Bootstrap

Actually I have this in my Browser :

[Browser Code through inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjDxm.png)

and this in my code

```html
<ng-template #newSlaVmData let-modal>
          <div class="modal-header modal-slaVMData">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">
              Add
            </h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
              <span aria-hidden="true">
                ×
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
```

As you can see, some code are generated by Bootstrap.

I want to know how can I change the CSS of "modal-dialog" (Browser code) ?

I tried different methods like adding this class in my SCSS file but it didn't work.

I use these dependencies:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3"
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `::ng-deep` pseudo-class to disable view-encapsulation. Add this to your .scss file:

```css
::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply overwrite the classes used by bootstrap, like this:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  background-color: black;
}
```

it's important to load your css file after the bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

You can add style after the class like

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="color:white"></div>
```

This will override the bootstrap class.

Comment: This indeed overrides the bootstrap style but, using in-line styles is bad, you would end up having styles in all over your template html